# Is there a way to get the windows like app launchers on xfce?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

I am tired of searching for a way to open apps like it is in windows or other DEs like cinnamon where you click the app launcher and it opens with leaving a indicator on the app launcher.
However in xfce it is totally different the best setup I could do was adding the app launcher and window buttons but its still not what I want this is what my current setup works like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install DockbarX or docklike panel plugins.

https://github.com/M7S/xfce4-dockbarx-plugin/

https://github.com/nsz32/docklike-plugin/